# jQuery not() working but throws 'unrecognized expression .' error

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of elements which I'm filtering using some links. The elements have classes which define whether they should be shown/hidden when the links are clicked. Everything works, except I get this error on each click:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: . jquery.js?v=f7cfcab3b68cbd79eec30032754a6719:3

It's something to do with my `.not()` selectors below. I've tried various alternatives (e.g. `:not`, and including/excluding single and double quotes, but nothing gets rid of the error:

```
var teamFilters = {
    dept: '',
    field: ''
}, filter;
$('.team-member-filters a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    filter = $(this).attr('class');
    if (link.parent().hasClass('active')) {
        link.parent().removeClass('active');
        teamFilters[filter] = '';
    } else {
        link.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        teamFilters[filter] = $(this).attr('id');
    }
    $('.main-body .team-member').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    $('.main-body .team-member').not('.' + teamFilters.dept).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 250);
    $('.main-body .team-member').not('.' + teamFilters.field).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 250);

    //console.log(teamFilters.dept);
});
```

The HTML for an individual element being filtered is:

```
<div class="team-member secretariate reducing">
    <div>
        <img src="/~climatex/files/cache/9d8d7862edc9f22dab5245926f79dace_f52.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="">
        <p class="name">Firstname Lastname</p>
        <p class="position">Job title</p>
    </div>
    <a class="email" href="mailto:name@email.com">name@email.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.url.com" target="_blank">www.url.com</a>
</div>
```

The `'.' + teamFilters.dept` selector is throwing the error, but since everything works I'm at a loss as to why.

I've tried to concatenate the `'.'+teamFilters.dept` variable outside the `.not()` selector but it doesn't make any difference.

I'm running jQuery 1.7.2.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your html seems to be mostly commented.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, have edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overquoted.

```
.not('".' + teamFilters.dept + '"')
```

should be

```
.not('.' + teamFilters.dept)
```

Of course, `teamFilters.dept` doesn't appear to ever change from this definition:

```
var teamFilters = {
    dept: '',
    field: ''
}
```

... and if that's the case, you'd end up with an invalid selector anyway.

Comment: Changing the quoting doesn't seem to help -- I still see the error. NB teamFilters' properties are set earlier in the `click` event

Comment: You were right! It's the invalid selector that does it -- because it attempts to select both `teamFilters.dept` and `teamFilters.field` every time, on page load both of those aren't set, hence the error. I've added in an `if` statement to test if they exist before attempting to select. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need quotes there if you're just filtering out classes:

```
.not('.' + teamFilters.dept)
```

Comment: Yep it works when I select in the way you've shown, but I still see the error. I'll edit the OP to reflect this.

Comment: What's the value of teamfilters.dept?

Comment: I sorted it out -- the problem was I was trying to select every time a filter was clicked, but the first click (by definition) only defines one of the two filters, hence the error. I fixed it by testing to see if the object's properties have a value before attempting to use them to construct the selector.